# How to run SSIS jobs sequentially with SQL Agent

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-agent

I have 5 SSIS jobs to run sequentially. For that I have created a job with 5 steps, each one is associated to one SSIS. The steps are configured as follows:

- EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job name of SSIS
- If success, go to next step.
- If error, quit the job.

All steps are chained as mentioned above but apparently some steps are running in parallel.

What more do I have to do to make them run sequentially?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Out of interest, why are you still using `msdb` and not `SSISDB`? As for what you're asking, why not have a "master" package that calls each package sequentially (Using the Execute Package Task) in the Control Flow and just run that package?

Comment: Just entered the project and fixing some bugs.... Will have a look at it, thanks

Comment: Actually, I miss read what you wrote, I thought you were using `msdb` to start the package, but you're using it to start an Agent Job; apologies. You probably *are* using SSISDB, so my point about the "master" package probably seems the best idea; in my view.

Comment: To run sequentially, use the execute SSIS step. Don't call a sql job, which is asynchronous

Comment: Create one job with each step calling a SSIS package in the order you want them to execute.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, your issue stems from the fact that the `msdb.dbo.sp_start_job` procedure does exactly what it says: it starts a job and then exits. **It doesn't wait for the job in question to complete.**

If you need to serialise the execution of your packages, in your main job you will need to execute the packages themselves, not the other jobs that run them. This way, the next package will not start until the previous one has finished.